# ASP.NET MVC3 routing with areas not working only on deployment server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I have an Asp.Net MVC3 web applications, which uses Areas.

When I run it from visual studio using IISEXPRESS everything is working just fine. 
But when I deploy the application to my test server, the application won't render any views which are located in areas.

On my development machine the url that is generated looks like this:
http://localhost:58366/myapp/settings/convertemplates
(settings = the name of the area, converttemplates = name of controller)

on the test server, the url is different:
http://testserver/myapp/converttemplates?Area=settings

How is it possible the routing works as expected on my development machine, but fails on the test server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem... (but I do not understand the implications...)

the config contained the following line

```
<system.web>

<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" optimizeCompilations="true">
```

when I remove **optimizeCompilations="true"** routing again works like expected.